# PMD e checkstyle no windows 10

Tags: java, java-8

Como e qual link para instalar PMD e Checkstyle no windows 10.
So vejo tutor de linux .

Comment: Lembra que Java é uma linguagem independente de plataforma? Então, o link para baixar o PMD e o checkstyle são os mesmos em qualquer sistema operacional.

Answer (score 1):

Você já deve ter ouvido falar que Java é uma linguagem independente de plataforma. Então, o link para baixar o PMD e o checkstyle são os mesmos em qualquer sistema operacional.

O link para baixar o Checkstyle 8.3: http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/8.3/checkstyle-8.3.jar

Para incluir ele em seu sistema com Maven/Gradle/Ivy/etc: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.puppycrawl.tools/checkstyle/8.3

O link para baixar o PMD 5.8.1: https://github.com/pmd/pmd/releases/download/pmd_releases%2F5.8.1/pmd-bin-5.8.1.zip

Para incluir ele em seu sistema com Maven/Gradle/Ivy/etc: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.pmd/pmd/5.8.1

O PMD até que pode dar um trabalhinho para instalar no Windows. [Veja na página oficial](https://pmd.github.io/):

> 1. Download [pmd-bin-5.8.1.zip](https://github.com/pmd/pmd/releases/download/pmd_releases%2F5.8.1/pmd-bin-5.8.1.zip)
> 2. Extract the zip-archive, e.g. to `C:\pmd-bin-5.8.1`
> 3. Add folder `C:\pmd-bin-5.8.1\bin` to PATH, either
>
>    1. Permanently: Using System Properties dialog > Environment variables > Append to PATH variable
>    2. Temporarily, at command line: `SET PATH=C:\pmd-bin-5.8.1;%PATH%`
> 4. Execute at command line: `pmd.bat -d c:\src -R java-basic -f text`
>      Checkout the [existing rules](https://pmd.github.io/pmd-5.8.1/pmd-java/rules/index.html).

Traduzindo:

> 1. Baixe o [pmd-bin-5.8.1.zip](https://github.com/pmd/pmd/releases/download/pmd_releases%2F5.8.1/pmd-bin-5.8.1.zip)
> 2. Extraia o arquivo zip, por exemplo, para `C:\pmd-bin-5.8.1`
> 3. Adicione a pasta `C:\pmd-bin-5.8.1\bin` ao PATH, de uma dessas formas
>
>    1. Permanentemente: Usando a caixa de diálogo das propridades do sistema > Variáveis de ambiente > Adicionar à variável PATH
>    2. Temporariamente, na linha de comando: `SET PATH=C:\pmd-bin-5.8.1;%PATH%`
> 4. Execute na linha de comando: `pmd.bat -d c:\src -R java-basic -f text`
>      Baixe as [regras existentes](https://pmd.github.io/pmd-5.8.1/pmd-java/rules/index.html).

Comment: Quero baixar o PMD direto no link no eclipse usando o SO win 10 automaticamente.